# MySQL UNION or Create an intermediate Table?

Tags: mysql, union

I have two Table (MySQL, InnoDB) which are identical to each other holding some score information. I want to create a leader-board out of those two.
Scores from Table-1 have more wight (^2) in comparison to Table-2.

One strategy is two write a SQL Query using UNION statement and get the result on the fly and the other is to create another table and insert data from both tables to that on timely basis. (e.g Cron-Job)

My question is how expensive this UNION query would be?

```
SELECT 
    username,
    specialId,
    SUM(correct) points,
    IFNULL((SUM(foracc) / SUM(completegames)), 0) accuracy
FROM
    ((SELECT 
        u.username,
        u.specialId,
        POW(p.correct, 2) as correct,
        p.correct as foracc, #to calcuate accuracy
        p.completegames
    FROM
        Table_01 p
    LEFT JOIN users u ON u.userid = p.userid
    WHERE
        p.year = 2012 AND p.type = 1) UNION (SELECT 
        u.username,
        u.specialId,
        p.correct,
        p.correct as foracc, #to calcuate accuracy
        p.completegames
    FROM
        Table_02 p
    LEFT JOIN users u ON u.userid = p.userid
    WHERE
        p.year = 2012 AND p.type = 1)) AS Table_aggregatedscore
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY points DESC , acc DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Both Table_01 and Table_02 are having more than 20million rows.

PS. I don't have time/ability to benchmark those two things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UNION ALL` does not check for unique rows, so it can speed up query.

You can also move some aggregation inside subselects to reduce intermediate amount of data (in case your aggregation reduces row count).

Or you can `LEFT JOIN` (instead of `UNION`) both tables with `users` and move `POW` inside `SUM`, `(SUM(Table_02.correct) + SUM(POW(Table_01.correct, 2))) AS  points`.

Answer (score 1):

Build a second table.  Once you've loaded data, add a trigger on the original tables to insert into the new table on new record creation in either original table  that way you don't have to run batches.